# How can I resolve the warning "Use of assignment to $[ is deprecated"?

Tags: perl

I have a program that I downloaded from an older computer to a newer one.  It has the following snippet of code:

```
#!/bin/perl -w

use strict;

$[ = 1;    # set array base to 1
$, = ' ';    # set output field separator
$\ = "\n";    # set output record separator
```

However, when I try to run the script I get the following error message:

```
Use of assignment to $[ is deprecated at ./test.pl line 5.
```

Any idea on how to resolve this?

I am using the following version of perl:

```
This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
```

Answer (score 9):

The use of `$[` has been discouraged, deprecated, and [all but disallowed](https://perl6.org/archive/rfc/355.html). See [it in perlvar](http://search.cpan.org/%7Erjbs/perl-5.24.0/pod/perlvar.pod#$%5B) (it is in [Deprecated and Removed Variables](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Deprecated-and-removed-variables) section<sup>†</sup>) and see the core [arybase](http://search.cpan.org/%7Erjbs/perl-5.24.0/ext/arybase/arybase.pm) where it's been moved.

Still, if you must, you can disable this particular [warning category](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html#Category-Hierarchy)   (*Update: only in pre-v5.30)<sup>†</sup>*

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# Restrict the scope as much as possible
{ 
    no warnings 'deprecated';
    $[ = 1;                               # NOT possible in v5.30+
    
    # ...
}
```

Now it will not print that warning, and it will work since it is still legal.  (*Not in v5.30+*) <sup>†</sup>

Note that this also changes other offsets, for strings for example, but *not* yet some others. It is a very, very old "feature," please read the documentation.

I'd strongly recommend **rewriting the script**, if at all possible.

---

<sup>†</sup>  Still the same status [in v5.30](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$%5B)   ... but:   "*Assigning non-zero to `$[` is no longer possible*".

Thus you *cannot* anymore assign, regardless of warnings or errors (those can be suppressed or handled).  Then either **rewrite the script** or use [Array::Base](https://metacpan.org/pod/Array::Base) if you must work with that offset, as in [mob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41234840/4653379)

Comment: Thanks to @ArborealAnole and their proposed edit, which I misunderstood and rejected and so they posted an answer (which I did get), for bringing it to my attention that in v5.30 on can't anymore assign (non-zero) to this variable (even though its status hasn't changed)

Answer (score 7):

The module [`Array::Base`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Array::Base) implements the array index offset feature in modern versions of perl. For a self-constrained script, beginning the script with

```
use Array::Base (1);
```

should behave pretty similarly to an older script that says

```
$[ = 1;
```

at the top, but see the docs for some [potentially important disclaimers](https://metacpan.org/pod/Array::Base#Differences-from).

Answer (score 4):

Short-term: You can silence this warning by replacing the `-w` flag (enable some warnings) in the first line with `-X` (disable all warnings).

Long-term: This script probably just needs to be rewritten entirely. The use of the `$[` variable (array base index) has been discouraged since the release of Perl 5.0 (in 1994!!); its presence in this file means that it must be very old indeed.

Comment: It's better to suppress warnings locally: `{ no warnings; $[ = 1; }`. Leave the `-w` in place, or better, replace it by `use warnings;`.

Comment: @KeithThompson True. On the other hand, it's futureproofing in case any of the other obsolete features used in the script get deprecated later on…

Comment: @duskwuff: I think you and I might define "futureproofing" differently. :-P

Comment: @ruakh I mean, pragmatically speaking… whether the problem is "fixed" with a lexical `no warnings` or with `-X`, the script is probably not getting rewritten in modern Perl either way. One of the two solutions means the OP has to ask again when Perl deprecates something new, the other lets the script keep working until it's broken beyond repair…

Answer (score 1):

[Since Perl v5.30](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Deprecated-and-removed-variables), assignment to `$[` of anything but `0` produces an error. The workaround in zdim's answer no longer applies. The module [Array::Base](http://metacpan.org/pod/Array::Base) mentioned by mob still works however.